# Google maps api V3, polylines and projections

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

The following problem is attempted using google maps api V3.

Given are two lat long positions 1 and 2. I need to dray a polygon as shown in the figure http://tinypic.com/r/30mwdjn/5. d_1 is the length of the line joining the points 1 and 2. Also known are the angles A, length d_2 and it is safe to assume that all the distances in the figure can be computed using trigonometry. I am trying to draw the polygon on the google maps using the API V3. All I have now is a polyline joining 1 and 2. I looked up projection in the API reference, which gives me the x and y coordinates. Now how to go about fining the latitude and longitude of the other corner points?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long the distances between your points are, but you need to convert from 2D to 3D as Lat/Lon will represent points on a globe. If you simply take the distances like A or d_2 (even d_1), you ignore the fact that you are on top of a globe.
I don't think this is a one-step formula. Should be possible with polar coordinates based on the correct distances and angles.

Maybe this will help you:
[Examples for LatLon functions](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: I have taken the correct distances. The lengths are actually Haversine distances given lat and long.